# Python - Check file name for extension

Tags: python

Is there a way in Python to check a file name to see if its extension is included in the name?  My current workaround is to simply check if the name contains a . in it, and add an extension if it doesn't...this obviously won't catch files with . but no extension in the name (ie. 12.10.13_file).  Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: And why would `13_file` *not* be an extension? You'll need to define some rules as to what makes a valid extension here. There are no standard rules.

Comment: And if you have done that and decide that Martijn is right, use [`os.path.splitext`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext). It will return a tuple with the filename and the extension (which contains the ., i.e. `.13_file`) or an empty string as the second element.

Answer (score 2):

'12.10.13_file' as a filename, does have '13_file' as it's file extension. At least regarding the file system.

But, instead of finding the last . yourself, use [os.path.splitext](http://docs.python.org/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext):

```
import os
fileName, fileExtension = os.path.splitext('/path/yourfile.ext')

# Results in:
# fileName = '/path/yourfile'
# fileExtension = '.ext'
```

If you want to exclude certain extensions, you could blacklist those after you've used the above.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `libmagic` via https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-magic to determine "file types."  It's not 100% perfect, but a whole lot of files can be accurately classified this way, and then you can decide your own rules, such as `.txt` for text files, `.pdf` for PDFs, etc.

Don't think in terms of finding files with or without extensions--think of it in terms of classifying your files based on their content, ignoring their current names.